# Updating boolean value with SSJS Rows.Update returns 500 error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to update a boolean column (`new`) using the following SSJS:

```
        var targetDE = DataExtension.Init(DE);
        var processing = targetDE.Rows.Update(
            {
                attempts: 0,
                status: "static line here",
                new: false,
                code:null,
                description:null
            },
            ['subscriberkey'], [key]
        );
```

When I run this code in a cloudpage, it returns a 500 error. As soon as I remove the `new: false` line it works again. I have tried also using `'false'` and `0` but neither of these values work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` is a [reserved word/operator for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) which is what is causing the miscommunication and error in your code. If you change your keys to be quoted, it should work as expected.

e.g.

```js
        var targetDE = DataExtension.Init(DE);
        var processing = targetDE.Rows.Update(
            {
                "attempts": 0,
                "status": "static line here",
                "new": false,
                "code":null,
                "description":null
            },
            ['subscriberkey'], [key]
        );
```